# Laravel notification serialization problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-notification

I am using Laravel Notification to notify users about certain things. Everything works as expected but there are certain cases where I get the next error.

```
(1/1) InvalidPayloadException
Unable to JSON encode payload. Error code: 5
```

The thing that I noticed when I get these errors is that the users being notified have data in a BLOB column in the users table. My guess is that for some reason Laravel is not being able to serialize the values contained in the BLOB column and as a result of that I get the error shown above.

Actually, if I change the values of that column to NULL the notification process works perfectly. I tried to use the hidden and cast properties in the User model but it doesn't help.

Reading the documentation I haven't found the way to change that serialization so I can make it work. Is there anything I can to change this behavior?

I appreciate your comments. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found by yourself **JSON** does not accept binary data, the trick here is to encode the *BLOB* to **base64** so it can be used in a **JSON**, the only downside is that you have to decode it when you retrieve the **JSON**.

You can use an `accessor` on your model to be able to auto encode the *Blob field* when the **Model** is *serialized* in **JSON**, i.e.:

```
// in User Model
public function getBlobAttribute($value)
{
    return base64_encode($value);
}
```

You only have to remember to *decode* the **BLOB** when you use it as *real binary data* (for example if it's an image), i.e.:

```
$blob = base64_decode($model->blob)
```

Or you can write a method that retrieve the blob *without* using the `accessor`:

```
// in User Model
public function getRawBlob()
{
    $this->getOriginal('blob');
}
```

I Hope this help.

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.